# dynamically add param to userAuthorizationUri in oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, google-api, spring-security-oauth2

Sometimes user's refresh token in local DB becomes stale. To replenish I'm trying to add `prompt=consent` param while making the oauth2 call. I was trying to `@Autowire AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider` in my config class and in the `afterPropertiesSet` I was doing a `setTokenRequestEnhancer` and then realized that this bean is not even initialized via spring container when i looked the following code in `OAuth2RestTemplate`

`private AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProviderChain(Arrays.<AccessTokenProvider> asList(
            new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider(), new ImplicitAccessTokenProvider(),
            new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider(), new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider()));`

Searched if any spring code is calling `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.setAuthorizationRequestEnhancer(RequestEnhancer)` to learn how to access it, but no one is calling it.

**Question:** How to dynamically add a param to `userAuthorizationUri` while making oauth2 call?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I haven't found an elegant solution neither. I have noticed, however, that redirect is triggered by `UserRedirectRequiredException`.

I was able to dynamically add request params by registering custom filter that modifies this exception *on the fly*.

```
@Component
@Order(-102)
public class EnhanceUserRedirectFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (final UserRedirectRequiredException ex) {
            ex.getRequestParams().put("prompt", "consent");
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Please note, such servlet filter has to have higher precedence than Spring Security. In my case, *-102* is higher precedence than Spring Security default of *-100*.